# My changes in the masterpage are not showing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, 2019, custom-masterpage

I made a change in one of my master pages however, the change isn't showing.  My previous ones are. When I preview it in the browser, there's a message:
***"Your HTML file isn't converted because it's not associated with a SharePoint file. You can associate it by editing its properties. Associating this file will overwrite any existing SharePoint file with the same name."***

I published the html file but not sure what else to do.  Is there a step I am missing?